# Apply interior colour in a With-function to a filtered range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply an `interior colour` to a list of products in Range `B4:E15`. 
The colour switches between `yellow RGB(255,255,0)` and `gray RGB (217,217,217)` so in the end it should look like this:

---

[image]

---

I tried to go with this `VBA`:

```
Option Explicit
    Sub Apply_Interior_Colour111()
      Dim lr As Long, fr As Long, i As Long
      Dim grey As Long, yellow As Long, interior_colour As Long
    
    With Sheet1
    
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    fr = 4
    
    grey = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        
        For i = fr To lr
        If i = fr Then
        interior_colour = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        ElseIf .Cells(i, 2).Value <> .Cells(i, 2).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
    
            If interior_colour = grey Then
            interior_colour = yellow
            Else
            interior_colour = grey
            End If
            
        End If
            
        .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = interior_colour
            
        Next i
            
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

---

However, the result looks like this:

[image]

---

What do I need to change in the `VBA` so it is **only applied to the filtered data** and looks like in the first screenshot?

Comment: Work with the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`.

Comment: How do we know that `Product_E` has to be yellow? Will you apply the color after filtering the data?

Comment: Yes, it will be applied after filtering.

Comment: You mean by filtering by `Product_E`? So all filtered cells can be colored to yellow?

Comment: Could you not use conditional formatting for this?

Comment: @Vbasic2008: First the data is not filterd. Then I set a filter. After the filter is set I run the VBA manually.

Comment: When the filter is applied, I tried to color all the rows to grey and then color the filtered rows to yellow. Unfortunately the first part doesn't work on the non-filtered rows. The only thing that comes to mind is that you could create a filter object and store the filter properties in it then use `ShowAllData`, color the rows to grey and reapply the filter and then color the filtered cells to yellow. If you are content with manually applying grey to the unfiltered range, then `SpecialCells` will get you the yellow into the filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

### Apply Interior Color to Filtered Data

- I did not figure out why `rng.Interior.Color = grey` would not apply the grey color to the unfiltered rows.
- If your data has an empty column to the right and an empty row to the bottom, you can use the following:

**Compact Version**

```
Option Explicit

Sub applyInterior()
    
    Const FirstCell As String = "B4"
    Dim grey As Long
    grey = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    Dim yellow As Long
    yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    
    Dim FirstCellRange As Range
    Set FirstCellRange = Sheet1.Range(FirstCell)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = FirstCellRange.CurrentRegion
    Set rng = FirstCellRange _
      .Resize(rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - FirstCellRange.Row, _
              rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column - FirstCellRange.Column)
    
    Dim RowRange As Range
    For Each RowRange In rng.Rows
        RowRange.Interior.Color = grey
    Next RowRange
    
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = yellow

End Sub
```

**First Version**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Apply_Interior_Colour111()
    
    Const FirstCell As String = "B4"
    Dim grey As Long
    grey = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    Dim yellow As Long
    yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = defineEndRange(Sheet1.Range(FirstCell))
    Dim RowRange As Range
    For Each RowRange In rng.Rows
        RowRange.Interior.Color = grey
    Next RowRange
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = yellow

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Defines the range from a specified first cell to the last cell
'               of its Current Region. It is the Current Region minus the cells
'               to the left and above of the specified first cell.
' Remarks:      If the specified first cell is "A1", then its Current Region
'               and its End Range are the same.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function defineEndRange(FirstCellRange As Range) _
         As Range
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "defineEndRange"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    ' Validate First Cell Range.
    If FirstCellRange Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NoFirstCellRange
    End If
    ' Define Current Region ('rng').
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = FirstCellRange.CurrentRegion
    ' Define End Range.
    Set defineEndRange = FirstCellRange _
      .Resize(rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - FirstCellRange.Row, _
              rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column - FirstCellRange.Column)
    ' Exit.
    GoTo ProcExit
' Labels
NoFirstCellRange:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No First Cell Range."
    GoTo ProcExit
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo ProcExit
ProcExit:
End Function
```